# How to start Mail and Calendar applications with powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-10, powershell-3.0

How can I start Mail and Calendar applications from the store using powershell? I've found a lot of examples how to start other apps, but I can not find proper names of them ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most user-friendly solution I've found is to use the URI-protocols that many modern apps have. Use the file type/protocol associations list in the control panel to find your app's URI-protocol.

Outlook Mail:

```
Start-Process ms-unistore-email:
Start-Process outlookmail:
```

Outlook Calendar:

```
Start-Process outlookcal:
```

You can shorten it to `start outlookmail:` if you need as `start` is an alias for `Start-Process`

Comment: Can this be extended to open any given email account or folder in any given email account (assuming said email account is currently logged into in the Mail app)? I posted this as a separate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70689854/how-to-open-email-app-to-specific-folder-powershell