# How to open email app to specific folder PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, email, custom-url-protocol

I want to open the Windows Mail app to a specific folder within a specific account from PowerShell. Is this possible?

I learned from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37331949/how-to-start-mail-and-calendar-applications-with-powershell) that the mail program can be launched using the custom URI `ms-unistore-email:`.

I can successfully launch the email app with the following PowerShell line:

```
Start-Process ms-unistore-email:
```

Of course, this simply opens the Inbox of the first account (same as if you launch the Windows Mail app from the Windows Start Menu). Is there a way to open a different account's inbox? Or even any arbitrary folder within the email account?

I tried the following, but it does not appear to work.

```
# This does NOT work to open the inbox of "myemail@gmail.com"
Start-Process ms-unistore-email:[myemail@gmail.com]
```

EDIT:

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51011949/how-to-launch-windows-10-mail-app-in-specific-folder?rq=1) seems to suggest this is not possible, but is from more than 3 years ago. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing has been changed so far. You can't navigate anywhere in the mail app using a command-line parameter. The application developers are responsible for implementing corresponding handlers, see [Handle URI activation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation) for more information on that. So, I'd suggest suggesting a feature to the product team at MS or opening a support case with MS.